# 3 people distributed at random problem

Tags: probability

Along a road $1$ mile long are $3$ people distributed at random. Find the probability that no $2$ people are less than a distance of d miles apart when $d \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

I have read this solution: 
Let $x_i$ be the position of the $i^{th}$ person. I am not sure how to get the following joint density?

$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=3!$,  $0<x_1<x_2<x_3<1$

Is there any other solution to this problem that is more intuitive?

Answer (score 1):

This follows from symmetry. In particular, consider all possible sets of orderings of $x_1, x_2$, and $x_3$. (So let $A_1 = \{ x_1 < x_2 < x_3 \}, A_2 = \{ x_2 < x_1 < x_3 \},...$. How many are there? Let that be $N$. (How many ways can you sort $x_1, x_2$ and $x_3$? That is $N$)

Now, note that the union of all these sets is *almost* $[0,1]^3$, which has area 1. (You only did not include the cases where any two are equal, but what is the probability of $X_1 = X_2$ if they are i.i.d continuous random variables?). Since you know that these sets have the same volume by the symmetry, the volume of each of these is $\frac{1}{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

What is your solution again? I do not understand. This is a continuous problem, what would 3! represent here? You need to work with the joint probability density function $f: [0,1]^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is constant 1.

Hint: compute the probability of the complement event. 
It consists of those points $x,y,z$ in all permutations such that $y\geq x+d$ and $z\geq y+d$.